# " java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable" error is coming when TestNG test cases run on Jenkins install on ubuntu 14.1

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

"java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable" error is coming when TestNG test cases run on Jenkins install on ubuntu 14.1. As if Chromedriver is not starting on jenkin installed on ubuntu, Same configuration tried on jenkin install on Window os, works fine.Please provide me any solution if any.

Console Ouput :

```
run:
   [testng] org.testng.TestNGException: 
   [testng] Cannot instantiate class TestCase.NewsArticles_Section_TC
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:38)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:110)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:186)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:153)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:522)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1289)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1364)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1333)
   [testng] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   [testng]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   [testng]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
   [testng]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
   [testng]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
   [testng]     ... 19 more
   [testng] Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   [testng]     at pagefactory.NewsArticle_Section.NewsArticle_Section_Add.<init>(NewsArticle_Section_Add.java:18)
   [testng]     at TestCase.NewsArticles_Section_TC.<init>(NewsArticles_Section_TC.java:14)
   [testng]     ... 24 more
   [testng] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Mentis kitchen test/workspace/lib/chromedriver.exe
   [testng]     at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:126)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:117)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$0(ChromeDriverService.java:1)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:118)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:291)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:82)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:117)
   [testng]     at reusablescript.driver.<clinit>(driver.java:12)
   [testng]     ... 26 more
   [testng] The tests failed.

makexsltreports:
```

Comment: Is it permission related problem??

Comment: yes I think the file you are accessing doesn't have execution permission. add execution permission to the file. From terminal  chmod rwx path/chromedriver

Comment: @vicky Added executable permission  as PreBuild Action : chmod a+x /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Mentis\ kitchen\ test/workspace/lib/chromedriver

Comment: ChromeDriver Started But Still "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally" error is coming

Comment: Is it compatible issue??, But I am using latest version of chromedriver 2.16, Chrome v33, selenium 2.46, open-jdk 7. Please suggest

Comment: @shwetha Could you try launching chromedriver with --verbose --log-path=chromedriver.log and post your log file?

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you are trying to run `chromedriver.exe` on Linux. You have to download binary file for Linux. `.exe` from stack trace doesn't look like correct one.

Then you have to add `executable flag` to it `chmod +x chromedriver`

Comment: I have had this error in the past and this is exactly what it was.

Comment: This error can also happen on Mac. All I did was go here and download the correct chromedriver for Mac https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Given below permission to chromedriver and it works.

chmod 777 chromedriver

As previous answer there is no relevance to the .exe part in stack trace