# Selenium Webdriver Tests fail on Jenkins(**Linux**) "The driver is not executable"

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to build my maven project with jenkins on Linux, but my selenium tests fails with this exception

> Running TestSuite
>   Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@61db2215
>   Tests run: 6, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 5, Time elapsed: 0.51 sec <<< FAILURE!
>   setup(selenium.TestSelenium)  Time elapsed: 0.392 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Synapse Control Center/workspace/ControlCenterTests/./src/test/resources/driver/chromedriver.exe
>       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:200)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:125)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:116)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:116)
>       at selenium.TestSelenium.setup(TestSelenium.java:43)

I understand that I used **selenium webdriver** for the windows not linux. 
[“ java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable” error is coming when TestNG test cases run on Jenkins install on ubuntu 14.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000190/java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-driver-is-not-executable-error-is-coming)
And I want to make it running on linux machine, but I don't really have much experience with it. How exactly could I fix it? THX

Answer (score 2):

Make chromedriver file executable using

**chmod +x chromedriver**

Also remove **maven clean** from build since it resets

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462100/driver-is-not-executable-error-in-jenkins-but-its-running-in-local-machine-macb

I did these steps still getting same error can you help me?

our Jenkins server is running in linux server and my machine is Mac. and test scripts is running in local not running in Jenkins

Answer (score -5):

First you need add chrome webdriver dependency to POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.48.2</version>
</dependency>
```

then you can use it :

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

you can find it more detailed:[link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started)