# How to execute chrome driver exe file in jenkin Linux server

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing an issue while executing the selenium scripts from jerkin.
The jenkin has the Linux server while executing the scripts its shows error as
**The driver is not executable: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/AutomationTesting/src/test/java/resources/chromedriver.exe**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Webdriver Tests fail on Jenkins(\*\*Linux\*\*) "The driver is not executable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391520/selenium-webdriver-tests-fail-on-jenkinslinux-the-driver-is-not-executabl)

Comment: Use Linux compatible driver.The above driver path ends with .exe .