# Driver is not executable error in Jenkins but its running in Local Machine (MacBook)

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

[image: Jenkins server file][image]

I am working on MacBook. Our Jenkins server is running in linux server when I running tests via testing.xml file all test classes are running but when I run Jenkins build its not getting run
Error is saying driver is not executable

I have created maven project in Jenkins and give repo url of this project from bitbucket

anyone help me to sort out this issue ?

```
    [INFO] Running TestSuite
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TravelCenterSeleniumJenkinsIntegrationCMB/target/classes/chromedriver
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
    at utils.TestApp2.openBrowser(TestApp2.java:59)
    at uk.TravelcCenter_Tests.Sports_Shows_Tests.setUp(Sports_Shows_Tests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:63)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:348)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:302)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:695)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
```

Comment: can you run `ls -la` in the directory where your driver resides? what permissions are defined for your driver file?

Comment: run ls -la in local machine or Jenkins server?

Comment: On Jenkins server

Comment: please post the text of the error, not a poorly cropped screen shot.

Comment: Text of error updated

Comment: This is permission issue. Please check the permissions of chromedriver. Give 755

Comment: where can I check permissions of driver in local or Jenkins server?

Comment: To clarify, (works on local) ? When you run this test directly in a SSH on the same jenkins "agent", it works fine?

Comment: This questin is sorted, there was issue on my Jenkins configuration

Answer (score 0):

My guess - Exactly what the error says, the driver is not executable. SSH into the server and see if

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TravelCenterSeleniumJenkinsIntegrationCMB/target/classes/chromedriver
```

fixes it (777 grants read/ write/ execute permissions to a file for user, group, and others respectively). If you can't SSH in whatever provisions your Jenkins server probably needs to make the file executable on on startup

Comment: not working can you check my question I have add Jenkins server image also

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String osDetector() {
  String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowercase();
  if (os.contains("win") {
    return Windows;
  } else if(os.contains("nux") || os.contains("nix") {
    return Linux;
  } else {
    return "OtherOs";
  }
}

// under the openDriverMethod
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
if (osDetector.contains("Windows") {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driver folder path");
} else if(osDetector.contains("Linux") {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driver folder path");
  //you need to add this one i guess!
  options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome");
}
```

Comment: can you explain below code public static String osDetector() {
  String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowercase();
  if (os.contains("win") {
    return Windows;
  } else if(os.contains("nux") || os.contains("nix") {
    return Linux;
  } else {
    return "OtherOs";
  }
}

Comment: find you current **jenkins running** operating system: `System.getProperty("os.name")`

os : **Windows or Linux or Unix** if you have mac i guess its should be **Unix** but i don't have any idea about mac!
once you get your os details, then use condition to write script based on jenkins running os..

Answer (score 0):

I have 10 test classes in my project, 2 classes are not well-defined chrome driver instance properly that's why I faced the above issue, its sorted now

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this solution is working for me. You can try once

In this case, when you installed Jenkins you have a user created for Jenkins and now you need to add permission for the Jenkins user

Here have some good explanation about this

https://medium.com/fusionqa/how-to-run-jenkins-using-the-root-user-in-linux-centos-79d96749ca5a#.pyshuihf0