# Not able to configure Nginx correctly as reverse proxy to both Jenkins and Nexus servers

Tags: nginx, jenkins, devops, reverse-proxy, nexus

I would like to have following `Nginx` urls by configuring `Nginx` as reverse proxy for both `Jenkins` and `Nexus`.

http://10.20.30.40 -> should display Nginx home page

http://10.20.30.40/jenkins -> should display Jenkins home page

http://10.20.30.40/nexus -> should display Nexus home page

After googling around I modified default configuration file and tried to check configuration. But I am getting following error while checking my configuration.

**Note:** I don't have any domain and ssl. Just using IP address for now.

**sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t**

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_pass" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:92
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
# Default server configuration
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

# Jenkins server configuration
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location /jenkins {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
        
# Nexus server configuration
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location /nexus {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two upstream block outside of server block, both for jenkins and nexus like this:

```
upstream backendjenkins {
        server <hostname>:8080;
          }

upstream backendnexus {
        server <hostname>:8081;
          }
```

Then, in the server block, mention like this:

```
location /jenkins {
           proxy_pass http://backendjenkins;
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
location /nexus {
           proxy_pass http://backendnexus;
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

Hope, this might help you.

Comment: For `private-ip` I tried following options `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `public-ip` but it fails at `sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t`. The error message `invalid host in upstream "http://localhost:8080"` and `invalid host in upstream "http://127.0.0.1:8080"` etc. How can I specify the correct value for `<private-ip>`?

Comment: After finding my private ip using `hostname -I` command and putting it in the file nginx does not start. I ran this command `sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t` and it gives this error
`nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "http://172.17.0.1:8080" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:20`

Comment: Updated the answer. Instead of private ip, try with hostname in upstream block.

Comment: Same error `nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "http://tools-server.kanaaritech.com:8080" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:20`

Comment: can anyone help me to sort out this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462100/driver-is-not-executable-error-in-jenkins-but-its-running-in-local-machine-macb